# Is there a difference between ctx.getValues() in `react-hook-form` and data got from onSubmit function handler?

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I always have thought those two were the same values.
But today I realised that there is a single difference which I have noticed as far as now.

Answer (score 0):

The data got from the onSubmit handler function was having the final transformed value where the Yup validator schema might have used the .transform() function.

Whereas the ctx.getValues() function returns the old values before/without transforming the values.

Example:
Yup Schema

[image: Yup schema]

This was my useForm hook and onSubmit handler function.
[image: Underlined with red]

NOTE: If you are setting the ctx values using .setValue() after onSubmit, then ctx form values will have the updated form values, not data.

Conclusion: **Data is not same as ctx.getValues()**